# It says that file doesnt exist when it does. when i do $file on the page it shows the variable and not view/herethehtmlformpostnumber.txt

Tags: php

The code is available below.
The issue is explained on the title of this post....

```
<?php

$filenumber = $_POST['filenumber'];
$file = 'view/$filenumber.txt';
$sharedfile = 'view/$shared.txt';
if(!isset($filenumber) || trim($filenumber) == '')
{
   echo "The file number field is empty or #$filenumber does not exist. Redirecting you in 3 seconds.";
   header ( "refresh:3;url=https://2.survivaltimepe.com" );
   exit;
}

$shared = $_POST['shared'];
if(!isset($shared) || trim($shared) == '')
{
   echo "The shared number field is empty or #$shared does not exist. Redirecting you in 3 seconds.";
   header ( "refresh:3;url=https://2.survivaltimepe.com" );
   exit;
}

$file = view/$filenumber.txt;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "The field is empty or the #$filenumber file number does not exist. Redirecting you in 3 seconds.<br>";
}

$sharedfile = view/$shared.txt;

if (file_exists($sharedfile)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "The field is empty or the #$shared shared number does not exist. Redirecting you in 3 seconds.";
    header ( "refresh:3;url=https://2.survivaltimepe.com" );
    exit;
}

$file = "view/$filenumber.txt";
unlink($file);

$sharedfile = "view/$shared.txt";
unlink($sharedfile);

echo ("File #$filenumber has been successfully removed.<br>Remember that you can always create a new link on the site.<br><br>Redirecting you in 10 seconds.");
header( "refresh:10;url=https://2.survivaltimepe.com" );

?>
```

title explains most of all that it displays the variable , instead it should be view/thehtmlformpostnumberhere.txt

Comment: That code is not even syntactically correct.

Comment: Right code? Im new.

Comment: Look at this:  
$sharedfile = view/$shared.txt;  Below you did it correctly:  $file = "view/$filenumber.txt";  These are strings.  You need to either use double quotes, single quotes or a combination of these along with concatenation.  This is the most basic fundamental of php.

Comment: Also, per the answer given, '$somevar' and "$somevar" work differently.  With "$somevar" it interpolates the string.  You need to read the manual a bit to understand this.  It's very important.

Comment: wow, thanks. I finally fixed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I echo a variable with single quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$file = 'view/$filenumber.txt';` to `$file = 'view/'.$filenumber'.'.txt';`

Update:
I saw in your script you have more of this cases. When you use a variable in a string use `'.$variable.'`

Comment: Or just use $file = "view/$filenumber.txt" as was done later in the code, that is filled with other syntax errors.

Comment: I'm having an issue <?php

        session_start();

$pwd= $_SESSION['pwd'];

        if($pwd == "admin";
        {
                header("location: https://server2.survivaltimepe.com/auth");
        }
        include ("auth.php");
        break;

?> says unexpected ; at 7 line

Comment: Its hard to see which line is line 7. Dont know your markup. But why you are using break; outside of a if?

Comment: @ChrisToxz I shouldn't be bumping into an old thread, but sorry, I was a newbie on PHP on that stage. I improved my skill a lot.