# Docker argument to a RUN echo command

Tags: docker

As part of a Dockerfile, I am attempting to modify a text file (ssh_config) to contain a variable passed through by the user (as an ARG) to the docker container at build time.

In my Dockerfile I have (this is not the entire file):

```
ARG key_name
RUN echo 'Host geoserver\n\
User user\n\
HostName 38.191.191.111\n\
IdentityFile /root/$key_name' >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

This collects the argument key_name, and then appends some text to the ssh_config text file.

This is run as follows:

```
docker build --build-arg key_name=GC -t pyramid .
```

When I check to see what has been written, the key_name variable hasn't been parsed, and instead has been written as text (so literally as $key_name).  Obviously I want it to be replaced with the variable passed through ARG.

I have tried using `${key_file}` instead of just `$key_file`, I just get the same text in the text file but with curly braces included.

So my question is, how can I use the ARG variable correctly within the RUN echo statement?

Comment: Have you tried `${key_name}` (with curly brackets) in your Dockerfile?

Comment: I have yes thanks, I'll add that to my question

Comment: Where is your `ARG`? Outside or inside of `FROM`? (yes, this makes a difference). Plus, try to remove the `'` from your `echo`.

Comment: Outside of 'FROM' I think.  FROM is the first line in my Dockerfile, but no indentation follows from that.  The ARG is working correctly, as it is also used to name a file which is copied over into the container, so I have confirmed the ARG is being correctly populated, its the echo part which is the problem I believe.  Removing ' did work however

Comment: So removing ' from echo worked, but now I lose my formatting, how can I use new line now, any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes

Comment: Thankyou @Munchkin, please submit an answer if you'd like the credit, turns out using " is the answer

Answer (score 71, accepted):

First: Make sure, your `ARG` comes **after** your `FROM`. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Second: [As you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes), variables won't be interpreted inside `''`, so use `""` instead.

Comment: Thank you! 
In my case it was ARG before FROM

Comment: No, it just takes the echo "$VARIABLE" literally and displays RUN echo "$VARIABLE" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 15):

When you surround the variable with single quotes it doesn't get replaced.

If you need the single qoutes in the file just surround everything with double quotes, otherwise just remove the single quotes all together.

```
ARG key_name
RUN echo "'Host geoserver\n\
User user\n\
HostName 38.191.191.111\n\
IdentityFile /root/$key_name'" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment: Nope, not the answer. Just takes it literally still.

Comment: What if you move the single quote to before `$key_name"` ?