# echo to file in docker file fails when building from armhf/ubuntu in dind

Tags: docker, ubuntu, arm, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I am using CI pipelines on Gitlab to build docker images for deployment to Raspbian. Since my builds need to access some private NPM packages, I include in the Docker file the following line which creates a token file using the value stored in environment variable $NPM_TOKEN:

```
RUN echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN > ~/.npmrc
```

This works fine when building from my usual image (`resin/raspberrypi3-node`). However one of my containers is built from `armhf/ubuntu`. When the above line is executed, the build fails with the following error:

```sh
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
The command '/bin/sh -c echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN >> ~/.npmrc' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The build runs fine from `docker build` on my development machine (Windows 10) but not within the gitlab pipeline.

I have tried stripping down my docker and pipeline files to the bare minimum, and removed the environment variable and the tilde from the path, and this still fails for the ubuntu (but not the resin) image.

Dockerfile.test.ubuntu:

```
FROM armhf/ubuntu

RUN echo hello > world.txt
```

Dockerfile.test.resin:

```
FROM resin/raspberrypi3-node

RUN echo hello > world.txt
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build_image:
  image: docker:git
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
  - docker build -f Dockerfile.test.resin . # Succeeds
  - docker build -f Dockerfile.test.ubuntu . # Fails
  only:
    - master
```

I have searched for similar issues and have seen this error reported when running a `.sh` file which contained `CRLF` combinations. Although I am developing on Windows, my IDE (VS Code) is set up to use `LF`, not `CRLF` and I have checked all the above files for compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459865/6309), try and use double-quotes for your echo argument:

```
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
```

And first, in your Dockerfile, do a `RUN ls -alrth ~/` to check the accessibility/presence of the target folder.

That error was also reported in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/build-multi-arch-docker-image/23569) (without any answer), with [an example](https://gitlab.com/jeremie.drouet/multiarch-ci) where the final version [of the Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/jeremie.drouet/multiarch-ci/commits/master/Dockerfile), as seen here, use this [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/jeremie.drouet/multiarch-ci/blob/c80077814f25d339b112455b9de117a6a3dda258/.gitlab-ci.yml).

The [OP bighairdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062035/bighairdave) confirms in the comments:

> I copied the following [from the example @VonC gave](https://gitlab.com/jeremie.drouet/multiarch-ci/blob/c80077814f25d339b112455b9de117a6a3dda258/.gitlab-ci.yml#L20-25), and it worked:

```
variables: 
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375" 
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2 
before_script: 
  - docker run --rm --privileged hypriot/qemu-register
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but, no, this doesn't work.

Comment: @bighairdave The `RUN ls -alrth ~/` doesn't work either?

Comment: Thanks again VonC. Interestingly, `RUN ls -alrth ~/` does fail for the ubuntu image. But my simplified tests (see original question) don't attempt to write to ~/ so why would that affect the cat command?

Comment: @bighairdave I don't think this is linked to cat or echo. Compare your `gitlab-ci.yml` with the one I have found and mentioned in my edited answer.

Comment: I agree it's not linked to `cat` - that was a typo on my part since edited - but it's definitely a failure of `echo`. Every other part of the gitlab build works, and it only fails when building on that base image. Thanks for the links, but I don't really see how they relate to this specific problem.

Comment: @bighairdave Jeremy made his (similar) error message disappear with that `gitlab-ci.yml`: I proposed to compare it with yours and see if there is anything in it which could make your build work.

Comment: Thanks again @VonC. I will dig further into your example and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I copied the following from the example @VonC gave in the above answer, and it worked:

```
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  before_script:
    - docker run --rm --privileged hypriot/qemu-register
```
Thanks!

Comment: @bighairdave Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.