# Cannot connect to my Mysql DB with PHP7.0 and Apache2 (2 different VM)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL DB located on 192.168.23.140 from my Web Frontend on .23.139

Here is my code :

```
$servername = "192.168.23.140";
$username = "web";
$password = "rootnetwork";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname', $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Here is what i get :

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

I've been looking for some answers on the internet but none of them work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: did you configure mysql to accept connection from that ip? by default it binds to localhost and/or 127.0.0.1 (that is the ip notation for localhost)

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in single quoted strings. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I echo a variable with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 2):

$variables are not expanded in a single quotes string literal, they are only expanded in a double quoted string literals.

So

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

> You will also have to make sure that this MYSQL user account `web` is setup to allow connections from ip addresses that are not the ip of the machine running MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now i have :  Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: See the comment in yellow

Comment: | web   | 192.168.23.139 | 
| web   | 192.168.23.140 |

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL is started on the other machine

Comment: and i modified bind-address = 0.0.0.0
                        bind-address = 192.168.23.139

Comment: Have you checked the firewall in the machine running MySQL so port 3306 is open

Comment: Each MySQL Account has a DOMAIN `\`web\`@\`localhost\`` for example you need `web` to be allowed to connect from `.23.139` So `\`web\`@\`192.168.23.139\``

Comment: yes I already did that 

MariaDB [(none)]> select user,host from mysql.user;

+-------+----------------+
| user  | host           |
+-------+----------------+
| web   | 192.168.23.139 |
| web   | 192.168.23.140 |
| marco | localhost      |
| root  | localhost      |
+-------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Then check your FireWall. Connection refused is normally either MySQL not stated or cannot get through the firewall

Comment: where can i check my firewall ?

Comment: Now this is way beyond the original questions scope. But only you can answer about your Firewall. I dont even know which one you are using !!

Comment: Web has host 192.168.23.139, web has GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'web'@'192.168.23.139'.
I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: I changed bind-address = 192.168.23.139

Comment: I checked mysql/error.log and the last row is 2019-02-18 11:12:27 140351153025472 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.

Comment: YUP. But only if a connection request can traverse your FireWall!