# Pass php value to html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a simple php value to html but I cannot format it in the right way. How can I do this?

```
<?php
 
$html = '

<img src="'$val'.svg" alt="15"> //Does not work

';

$val = 5;
?>
```

Comment: You need to use double quotes if you want to include variables in a string... `"$val"` will be extracted to the variables value

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes#:~:text=Taken%20from%20php.net%3A%20%22,is%20no%20you%20can't.

Comment: This won't work if you define `$val` *after* the string you want to use it in though…

Comment: also `$val` defined after use it ?

Comment: I's say [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1066240) would be the better reason as a duplicate.

Comment: I used double quotes but that does not seem to work.

Comment: "*I used double quotes but that does not seem to work*" as already @deceze and Devsi pointed you you are trying to use variable **before** assigning it, move it higher, also read linked answers how to join variables in the strings. Bonus TIP: if you were using any good IDE, it would tell you a warning about using an unassigned variable. `$val = 5; $html = "<img src='{$val}.svg' alt='15'>";`

Comment: Bonus tip 2: do not use `?>` for terminating the PHP script, although it's valid and allowed in may cause some troubles in the longer run, especially when you'll try to modify headers. 1:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/1066240 scroll to *Whitespace after ?>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would try to format it this way:

```
<?php
        $val = 5;
        $html = "<img src='${val}.svg' alt='15'> ";
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you this works :)