# Docker build commands no output displayed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bamboo, bamboo-specs

my sh script is called by the ci-cd tool (BAMBOO). the sh script contains the docker build command. I am able to see the output in the ci-cd console which is its context
example

```
RUN ls -ll

RUN pwd
```

However, in the docker file, if I do cat/ls/PWD and so forth. I am not able to see any output. It simply shows the sha256 hash on the screen. I tried adding --progress=plain / DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0. but still showing sha. I need to check the file content because there are other issues coming with the following command in this file which is commented for now.

Could anyone please guide me? I have attached a ci-cd console reference image.

[image: ci-cd output]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, your `ARG` comes **after** the `FROM`.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

[As you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670879/can-i-echo-a-variable-with-single-quotes), variables won't be interpreted inside `''`, so use `""` instead.